# changing clicked element's style in array through javascript

Tags: javascript

my html code:

```
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement()">div1</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement()">div2</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement()">div3</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement()">div4</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement()">div5</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement()">div6</div>
<!-- javascript code -->
function clickonelement(){
mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");
for(i=0; i<mydiv.length; i++){
mydiv.item(i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
mydiv[this].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
}
}
css code
.mydiv{width:300px; height:30px;}
```

I want on onClick event to change clicked element's background to white and other elements background remain red in color but my code
    mydiv[this].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
is not working. please solve this problem in JavaScript only. I am in basic stage of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the element that you want to refer to with `this`, e.g. `onclick="clickonelement(this)"`:

```js
function clickonelement(elem) {
  mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");
  for (i = 0; i < mydiv.length; i++) {
    mydiv.item(i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement(this)">div1</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement(this)">div2</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement(this)">div3</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement(this)">div4</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement(this)">div5</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="clickonelement(this)">div6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is JS code for your HTML code, you need add `addEventListener`.

```
function clickonelement() {
  mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");

  for (var i = 0; i < mydiv.length; i++) {
    mydiv[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is just another way of achieving the same functionality.

Objective

1. To remove inline event handler
2. Use loop only once instead of looping over all the matched class name (`mydiv`) on every click.

Used javascript functions & concepts

1. [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) : - Used to select all matched elements with same class that is `mydiv`. It will return an nodelist containing all matched elements
2. [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):- is an array method which used to loop over list.It accepts three arguments. For this case two will be enough.
3. [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):- Is use to attach event to an element
4. [**Closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):These functions 'remember' the environment in which they were created.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
//Get all the matched Elements
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.mydiv");
//Use an variable to rememeber previous clicked element
var prevIndex = -1; // 
// Loop over the list
matches.forEach(function(item,index){
 (function(i){ //  A closure is created
    item.addEventListener('click',function(){
       // if any previous element was clicked then rest it's background
        if(prevIndex !== -1){
         matches[prevIndex].style.background="red";
        }
        // change background of current element
        item.style.background="#fff";
        // update prevIndex
        prevIndex = i;  
     })
    }(index))

})
```

Check this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ocju73p7/)

Comment: oh! but I can see it is working. Can you please confirm it.You need to click on the demo link.It will open a jsfiddle

Comment: yes! it is working but not in firefox:(
i had to see in chrome to verify after your clarification